# Marketing Cloud SQL Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I want to query a triggered send to get the sends done in last 30 days. I am using the following SQL query

```
select SubscriberKey,EventDate as SentTime,JobID
from _Sent
TriggeredSendCustomerKey = 10411 and 
EventDate > dateadd(d,-30,getdate())
```

However the system is retuirng the sent in last 30 days in UTC time zone. I want to get the results in Melbourne, Australia Time Zone. Is there a way to achive it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As looking at your SQL query, GetDate() will return the current time on the system. SFMC runs on CST (non-daylight savings observing), so you will always get back a CST datetime value in your result.

So ideally you're pulling in the 30 days of data comparing both EventDate and GetDate() in CST hence I do not assume you need to convert the CST to AEST/AEDT.

Also if you do need to convert the CST time to AEST/AEDT then you can achieve this by:

- `AEST = GETDATE() + 16 hours`
- `AEDT = GETDATE() + 17 hours`